# Tool to view invisible Unicode characters in text for Windows

Tags: windows, text-editor, plain-text, unicode

I have text that looks like this:

> واحد اثنين 12 000

I would like to see if the space between the `12` and the `000` is a normal space (U+0020) or a narrow no-break space (U+202F). I would also like to look up the Unicode characters used in the Arabic script.

Is there a tool on Windows that will let me paste text and will give me the Unicode code points contained in that text?

Comment: Like this one? r12a.github.io/app-conversion There are a bunch of tools online. If you need a standalone app then you need to be more specific, like do you need it for CLI, some kind of text editor, or?

Comment: @Destroy666 The link you posted doesn't show the Unicode code point for each character (although I guess you could work it out from the UTF-32 output).

Comment: I would like an offline graphical application. The trouble with CLI applications is that Windows Terminal converts whitespace characters to other whitespace characters, so you can't trust it when you paste text to it or from it.

Comment: So what's the exact goal? For everything including `12000` to be converted (the description doesn't really fit that, please edit accordingly with input/expected output)? Also, with CLI, you can just save the text to `.txt` file and then process it with a tool, but I guess  you want a quicker solution?

Comment: I'm not trying to "convert" text into something else. I'm trying to see what Unicode code points are contained in a text. For example, a text editor might display in its status bar the Unicode code point of the character that is currently by the cursor.

Comment: @Destroy666 Yes, I guess saving the text into a text file and then processing the text file on the command-line would work. But a GUI tool would be nicer and quicker.